# Unable to turn on bluetooth on my lenovo ideapad U310 using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth, ideapad

I'm a new linux user and I don't really understand the replies to similar queries. The toggle in the bluetooth settings won't turn on at all.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not 100% certain I have bluetooth installed.  I'm hopeless.

Comment: The bluetooth may be turned off by hardware on your computer - Apparently F7 (with a little airplane on it) controls the function of the bluetooth module.  Try pressing it one time (it may take a while to take effect) and then seeing if you can toggle the bluetooth with Ubuntu.  https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/u310_u410_ug_en.pdf

Comment: not sure where the answer went that I was commenting on, but to be clear, I already did the bluez install.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thank you, that's interesting, my f7 is for claret browsing apparently no little airplane icon.  I'll take a look at that link though.

Comment: also, airplane mode is off.

Answer (score 0):

First, check out if you have the Bluetooth LKM (Linux Kernel Module) enabled.

```
sudo lsmod | grep bluetooth
```

If you don't, try this.

```
sudo insmod bluetooth
```

If this fails,  you'll have to recompile your kernel to add Bluetooth support (unlikely, since Ubuntu has a rather good hardware detection). If th bluetooth LKM successfully loads, try troubleshooting the issue with **bluetoothctl**

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

Then

```
[bluetooth]# list
[Controllers list]
[bluetooth]# select [controller]
[bluetooth]# devices
```

That should give you a base for troubleshooting. Also, check **dmesg** to see if there's any issue with the LKM on boot-up.

Edit: removed yum command.

Comment: Also, try pressing the Fn key on your keyboard + the key with Bluetooth icon. Eg. Fn+F7.

Comment: I don't seem to have a bluetooth icon on my keyboard and checking dmesg is useless to me because I have no idea what I'm looking for.  I'm thinking maybe I need an ethernet connection from what I'm seeing... does that make any sense?

Comment: Ethernet and Bluetooth have nothing to do with each other, in this case. Did you run the lsmod and insmod commands? What's its output?

Comment: as far as I can tell it is enabled.  this is why I get with the ismod command: bluetooth             391196  10 bnep,rfcomm

Comment: * If you search your Bluetooth-enabled laptop with, say, your cellphone, does it appear? Can you pair it? Is there a device with your PC name or saying Ubuntu or something like that?
* Also, run `hciconfig -a` and check for something like "hci0"
* If nothing of this works, try installing blueman. `sudo apt-get install blueman`

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue in Cinnamon on Mint 17 (14.04 based), both with Network Manager and Bluetooth Manager.

I've successfully used the same hardware combo (ThinkPad T530 / Nokia E52) with Mint 14 (based on 12.10) via Network Manager for DUN to T-Mobile UMTS.

Now, I've connected it with a manual setup as in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothDialup): created `BluetoothDialup` chat and peers scripts, and modified `rfcomm.conf` to my specific options.

Then i used:

```
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 my-phone-MAC my-phone-Channel pon BluetoothDialup
```

It then works, if one can point routes and `dns` to the right direction. However, functionality that worked out of the box in 12.10 is broken.